# How to connect an event from different files? Javascript/Backbone

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I am trying to use the .on method for one file to listen to another, and if a change occurs, I want it to trigger a rendering of a new view. This is my attempt to even get something printed to the console and it is not working.

This is my router file:

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'views/page',
    'models/search',
    'views/search',
    'text!templates/search.html'
], function($, _, Backbone, PageV, SearchM, SearchV, SearchT) { 
    var vent = _.extend({}, Backbone.Events);
    var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend ({
        routes: {
            'page/:id': 'showPage',
            's': 'showView'
        }
    });
    var initialize = function () {
        var app_router
        app_router = new AppRouter;
        app_router.on('route:showPage', function (id) {
            var page = new PageV();
            page.render(id);
        });

        **app_router.on('route:showView', function () {
            var searchM = new SearchM({vent: vent});
            var search = new SearchV({model: searchM, vent: vent}); //
            $('#Sirius').html( SearchT );
            search.render();    
                vent.on('nextPage', this.printCons);
                function printCons () {
            console.log('printing from listening')
            };** 


        });


        Backbone.history.start();
    };
    return {
        initialize: initialize
    };
});
```

This is the Search view file, that is being rendered, but not calling the console.log function in the router (that is surrounded by stars)

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  'models/search',
  'text!templates/search.html',

], function($, _, Backbone, SearchM, SearchT){ 
  var vent = _.extend({}, Backbone.Events);
  var Search = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $("#Sirius"),

    events: {
      'submit #searchMusic': 'search'
    },

    search: function (e) {
      console.log('searching...');
      e.preventDefault();
      var _this, that;
      _this = this;
      that = this.model;
      //post instance to the server with the following input fields
      this.model.save({
        channel: $('#channel').val(),
        week: $('#week').val(),
        year: $('#year').val(),
        filter: $('#filter').val()
      },{success: storeMusic });

       function storeMusic (that, response, options) {
        console.log('store');
        //create new instance of the localStorage with the key name
        _this.model.localStorage = new Backbone.LocalStorage("music");

        _this.clearLocalStorage(_this);

        _this.saveToLocalStorage(response, _this);
      };

    },

      clearLocalStorage: function  (_this) {
        console.log('clear');
          //removes the items of the localStorage
          _this.model.localStorage._clear();

          //pops out the first key in the records
          _this.model.localStorage.records.shift();

        },
        saveToLocalStorage: function  (response, _this) {
          console.log('save');
         _this.model.save({music: response}, {success: _this.nextPage});
        },


        nextPage: function  (_this, response, options) {
          console.log('entered next page');
          vent.trigger('nextPage', this.model)

        } 
  });
    return Search;
});
```

The function is being called and everything works properly, I am working on making the event be heard on the router side so I can have a user navigate to another page after clicking the submit button and the response returned being stored successfully on the localstorage. The nextPage function does get called, but I do not think I am implementing the vent.trigger or .on correctly... I do call it in both the router and the view (var vent = ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var vent = _.extend({}, Backbone.Events);
```

vent is being initialised in both the js files, which create 2 different objects which is not connected. To fix this in search view file remove vent declaration. in next page function change

```
 vent.trigger('nextPage', this.model)
```

to

```
 var vent = this.model.get('vent');
 vent.trigger('nextPage', this.model)
```

Comment: Ya I got it working at the end, i did something similar to that, but yeah the two different variables was a problem

Comment: better, with requirejs,  I do maintain a global model instance, which can be loaded as dependency to any module, I do link all util methods and global variables there. This helps me listen for global model changes at view level.